# After Ctrl+Alt+F* system starts new Gnome session, not returns to old

Tags: 18.04, gnome, tty

Ctrl+Alt+F* works fine for tty, but it looks like switch to tty from gnome   kills Gnome session, cause I even don't see no runned gui apps (like browsers and IDE) when run sudo top in tty session.
What can I do to switch between tty and gnome without gnome's death?